# pushing repository X to a branch of repository Y

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

I'm working on a branch called `branch-abc` of a repository abc, say, `https://a@b.c/repository-abc.git`

I want to push all this code to a branch called `branch-xyz` of an another repository xyz, say, `https://x@y.z/repository-xyz.git`

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Are you using git bash or some git gui?
If you are using bash, you should just be able to do this:
*Make sure you are on the branch. (git checkout branch-abc)
*Push the branch to the repo: (git push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `xyz` as a remote to your repository:

```
git remote add xyz https://x@y.z/repository-xyz.git
```

then checkout your branch and push it there:

```
git checkout branch-abc
git push xyz branch-abc
```